# How to pass extra_context when redirecting in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My views.py:

```
 @login_required
 def some_views(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = AddressCreateFrom(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             name = form.cleaned_data['Address']
             ip_value = form.cleaned_data['value']
             user_list = get_username(name)
             address_create = form.save()
             extra_context = {
                 'user_list': user_list
                 }
             return redirect_to(request, url=address_create.get_absolute_url())
     else:
         form = AddressCreateFrom()
     extra_context = {
         'form':AddressCreateFrom(initial={'user': request.user.pk})
         }
     return direct_to_template(request,'networks/user_form.html',extra_context)
```

In form.py:

```
 class AddressCreateFrom(forms.ModelForm):
     Address = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
     value = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
     class Meta:
         model = Network
         widgets = {
             'user': forms.HiddenInput()
           }
```

As you see that i am using Django model form with two extra Django form field i.e. `Address and value` in `AddressCreateForm` class. I need all of the field at the time of rendering the template.

Indeed `some_views` method are working fine but i also want render some extra data written in `context_dictionary` i.e. `user_list` to a requesting `URL` i.e. `address_create.get_absolute_url()`.

If i am not wrong, if we are handling with the database we have to use `redirect_to` method.  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the extra_context supposed to be for? Why would a redirect need any context of any sort?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am trying to pass the uesr_list variable (which is a list data type) with the Network model field to the template. I am getting this user_list after doing some calculation on the bases of ***Address and ip_value*** fields. If i did in this way then i can't render the ***user_list*** variable to template

Comment: -1 for "WHAT". I was asking for the trick. Is that something wrong with the question

Comment: What template? You're redirecting, not rendering a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A redirect will return a HTTP response with status code 301 or 302, and the location to redirect to:

```
301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Location: http://www.example.com/new-url/
```

There is no template rendered by the original view, so you can't pass `extra_context` to it.

The user's browser will usually follow the redirect, and request the new URL.

If you want to display information about a particular user in the next view, you have to do something like:

1. design your URL pattern to include the user id, e.g. `/users/200/`,
2. include it as a get parameter e.g. `/users/?id=200`, then fetch the user id from `request.GET` in the view.
3. store the user_id in the session
4. Before redirecting, create a message using the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) using the user data.

Then in the view that you redirect to, you can fetch the user from the database, and add it to the template context.

Answer (score 2):

Context, Extra Context and POST Data will not survive the redirect.

Here is what you can do.

```
# before the redirect
....
request.session['user_list'] = user_list
return redirect_to(request, url=address_create.get_absolute_url())

# after the redirect (in the views.py that handles your redirect)
....
user_list = request.session['user_list']
extra_context = { 'user_list': user_list }
....
# now you have the user_list in the extra_context and can send it to the rendering engine.
```

**Note:** This solution only works for redirects within your own server.