# Django HttpResponseRedirect is using the actual contents of index.html in url

Tags: php, django

New to django, from php background, went through polls app walkthrough, now I want to create a login page, but I've been having mounds of various errors. Here is something I'm confused about. I have a ACCOUNTS [app] and in  that directory I've got a TEMPLATES [subfolder] and in that there is only one folder, also named ACCOUNTS. Inside is all my templates, including index.html.

```
├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───templates
│   └───accounts
|         ->the index.html file
└───__pycache__

<html>
<head>
    <title>INDEX</title>
</head>
<body>
INDEX
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the url localhost:8000/accounts/ it literally takes the contents of index.html and plugs that into the URL

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%09%3Ctitle%3EINDEX%3C/title%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0AINDEX%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E

Accounts - views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, render
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from . import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('accounts/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'Kitty': 5
    })
    return HttpResponseRedirect(template.render(context))
```

Can somebody please explain (1) Why my current code is behaving like this (2) Potential fixes?

Thanks, I'm open to read up on or learn something necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) class is useful if you want to redirect the user to another url.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/other-url/")
```

In your case, you have rendered a template context. Because you are passing the rendered template to `HttpResponseRedirect`, it treats it as the url to redirect to.

The easiest fix is to use a regular `HttpResponse` instead.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('accounts/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'Kitty': 5
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Rendering a template and returning the response is very common, so you can shorten your code by using the `render` shortcut instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    template_name = 'accounts/index.html'
    context = {
        'Kitty': 5
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation in terms I can understand!

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same thing after submitting a form. I need to use `HttpResponseRedirect` while passing `context`. My view returns the entire HTML of the template. Any ideas?

Comment: @joshlsullivan You can't redirect while passing context. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850607/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-redirect-to-method-in-django-python/10851149#10851149). If that doesn't help, please open a new question.

Comment: @Alasdair Excellent. Thank you.